# Why "src/core" is ignored automatically in IntelliJ VCS

Tags: version-control, intellij-idea, cvs

I use IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1.

It's my source folder structure.
Module1/src/api
Module1/src/core

And I use CVS as Version Control System.

"api" source folder managed by IntelliJ VCS, but "core" sorce foloder not managed.
All files marked by the olive color and VCS sub menus is deactivated, except for the "check out".

Why "src/core" is ignored automatically in IntelliJ VCS?

I checked "File"->"Settings"->"Version Control"->"Ignored Files" but "core" not exists.

Comment: Are you sure the file is olive (indicating an ignored file) and not Brown (indicating the file is not known to Version Control)? If you open the "Changes" tool window, is the directory and/or its files listed in the "Unversioned Files" section? Does the "core" directory have a CVS subdirectory in it? (You'll need to go to the OS file explorer to check.) If not, the directory has not been added to CVS. Finally, check if you have either a project level or global `.cvsignoge` file that has "core" configured in it. (see

Comment: It's olive color exactly, not Brown. "Unversioned Files" section not include files in "core", but appear on "Modified" section in "Version Control Check Status Info" when I click "Check Directory Status" on "src" folder. Also, all .cvsignore files not includes "core". Furthermore, TortoiseCVS manage the "core" folder files as a cvs resource. So now, I use TortoiseCVS only for "core" folder.